# PHP if statement not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a related post section for a client. This related post section is cutomizable through the default WordPress theme customizer.

The user can select whether to display related posts, choose to display links or images for related posts as well as select how many related posts to show (max of 6). They can also upload custom default image to use as the default post thumbnail if they do not add one in the actual post.

Everything is working so far as it is supposed to with the exception of one area.

The area in question, is the section where they will be able to display the post thumbnail for related posts. I have written the following code:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    the_post_thumbnail('related-thumb');
elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail' ) ) :
    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
else :
    <img src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
endif; ?>
```

and then I get the following error message:

```
Parse error: parse error in D:\Server\wamp\www\demo\wp-content\themes\wp-forge\content-related.php on line 76
```

line 76 corresponds to the first image statement

and I am sure once that is corrected, I will get another error message regarding the second image statment

The following code is supposed to do the this:

***If*** the user has assigned a featured image to a post, that image will display

***elseif*** the user has not assigned a featured image and they have uploaded a custom default image, display the uploaded custom default image

***else*** if the user has not assigned a featured image and they have not uploaded a custom default image display the default image in the themes image folder

I have been trying for a few hours to correct this, and I have searched all over this site as well as other resources for a solution but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: You can't use php tag inside php tag, as you did in src attribute of img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your HTML code is an unescaped part of your PHP code and, therefore, not parsable.

Use one of the following variants:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    the_post_thumbnail('related-thumb');
elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail' ) ) :
    echo '<img src="' . get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail') . '" alt="' . the_title() . '" />';
else :
    echo '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-image.jpg" alt="' . the_title() . '" />';
endif; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    the_post_thumbnail('related-thumb');
elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail' ) ) :
    ?><img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_default_thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" /><?php
else :
    ?><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" /><?php
endif; ?>
```